# Logic level converter with voltage selector

Tags: digital-logic, spi

I want to use an ADG3304 logic converter. I know that this chip is bidirectional.

[image: Logic level converter]

I have designed a schematic of this solution. I want to switch between two voltage levels.

My questions are:

1. does it matter where I have Master and Slave devices (I know it is bidirectional. Just want to make sure)?
2. Will it work with equal values of VCCa and VCCb?

Comment: 1.) We don't know that chip better than you do. If it's bidirectional, it's bidirectional 2.) What does the data sheet say about VCCa and VCCb and their relationship?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.  Vcca must always be less than Vccy.  Or equal to.
2. Yes.

pay careful attention to the input-output voltages on page 3 of the datasheet.